# Python refreshing various excel files

Tags: python, excel

I would wish to run a python code such that many excel files can be refreshed. Currently i only have the code for running a single excel file. Any solutions/advice are much appreciated.

```
import win32com.client
import shutil
 
SourcePathName = 'C:/WhateverYourPathIs'
FileName = 'SpreadsheetFilename.xlsx'
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
Application.Visible = 1
Workbook = Application.Workbooks.open(SourcePathName + '/' + FileName)
Workbook.RefreshAll()
Workbook.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

To refresh several files in Excel, just put the filenames in a list and iterate through them. Open the Excel application once before the iteration then close it after the loop is complete:

```
import win32com.client
import shutil

SourcePathName = 'MyFiles'

filelist = [
'SpreadsheetFilename1.xlsx',
'SpreadsheetFilename2.xlsx',
'SpreadsheetFilename3.xlsx'
]

# open Excel app
Application = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
Application.Visible = 1

for FileName in filelist:  # each file
    Workbook = Application.Workbooks.open(SourcePathName + '/' + FileName)  # open file
    Workbook.RefreshAll()
    Workbook.Save()
    Workbook.Close()  # close file, Excel stays open

Application.Quit() # exit Excel
```